# Why is "git pull" trying to use CURL_OPENSSL_3 while libcurl4-openssl-dev is installed?

Tags: git, curl, openssl

When I run `git pull` I get the following error:

```
git-remote-https: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by git-remote-https)
```

Why is git trying to use `libcurl3-openssl-dev` while `libcurl4-openssl-dev` is already installed? The [solution](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/1680#event-1831142805) is that I install the following packages:

```
apt install libcurl3 libcurl-openssl1.0-dev
```

But the above command removes the following packages:

```
cmake libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

I don't want `cmake` to be removed! How can I fix this problem without having `cmake` removed?

Comment: Doesn't [git on Ubuntu 18.04 use `libcurl3-gnutls`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/git), and not OpenSSL? Where is your `git` from?

Answer (score 0):

When running git commands, I received the error:

> /home/username/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /home/username/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https)

This was due to the fact that I had compiled the latest version of [**git**](https://github.com/git/git) and then [upgraded glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10863613/1164465) by upgrading my Debian distribution.

The solution was to delete the git executable and re-compile git, which linked to the newer glibc.